# How to use AJAX and JSON in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, ajax

I have made a page for the car website using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Jquery. Now I want to make it dynamic. As I have a button named as `DROPDOWN` and I want that when I click on it, it fetches the new collection of the cars directly from the website of the particular brand.

I have a basic knowledge of JSON, AJAX. But I do not know that how exactly to apply it. I know that I'll have to store the JSON object in JS file and then will load that JSON data using AJAX and then to populate my car models. But how things will take place I have confusion in it.  https://jsfiddle.net/aw330go1/10/

Code and snippet given below:

**HTML CODE**

```
<html>
<head>
<title> SpaceCar </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/global.css"/> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale:1.0, user-scalable=0" />
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="srcipts/general.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header"> 
    <div class="logo"> <a href="#">Space<span>Run</span></a></div>
</div> 
<a class="mobile">MENU</a>
    <div id="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul id="nav">
        <li><a class="selected" href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Maruti</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyundai</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">RangeRover</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Purchases</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
     </li>
     </ul>
        <!--<button onclick="addimage();"> Click</button>-->
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <p> alright this is your dashboard</p>
        <div id="box">
        <div class="box-top">News</div>
        <div class="box-panel">
        this is some simple news ikdnksnd
        </div>
        </div>
    <div id="box">
        <div class="box-top">News</div>
        <div class="box-panel">
        what is idshfknsdkjfnjsdnkfnsdn
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box">
        <div class="box-top">News</div>
        <div class="box-panel">
        o i really khdkasndksnk is o asdjbaskjbdkasbdmaskdbas 
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="center">
            <img src="images (1).jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px" id="One"/>
            <img src="fisker-karma.jpg" style="width:189px;height:170px" id="Two"/>
            <img src="images.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px" id="Three"/>
            <img src="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px" id="Four"/>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS File:**

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css")
* { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}   
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    background-image: url("/home/kamna/admin page/bubble_f2.jpg");
} 
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
div#header {
    width: 500%;
    height: 50px;

    margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin;left:15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo a {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    color: #000;
}
.logo a span {
    font-weight: 300;
}
div#container {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #171717;
    float: left;
    color:#fff; /* change to whatever you want */
}
.content {
    width: auto;
    margin-left:250px;
    height: 500px;
    backgroud-color: #008000;
    color: #000;
    padding: 15px;
}
.content p {
    width:auto;
    font-size :0.73em;    
}
div#box {
    margin-top:15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
div#box .box-top {
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 1px #000;
    background-color: #2980b9;
    padding:5px;
    padding-left:15px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
div#box .box-panel {
padding:15px;
background-color: #fff;
color:#333;
}
ul#nav {
}
ul#nav li {
    list-style: none;

}
ul#nav li a {
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0A0A0A;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition:0.2s;
  -o-transition:0.2;
  transition:0.2s;
}
ul#nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #030303;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left:30px;
}
ul#nav li a.selected{
    background-color: #030303;
    color:#fff;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
.show {display:block;}
#center {
  margin:0px auto;
  width:960px; 
  height:auto;
  border:5px solid black;
  padding:10px;
 }
 #One {
     margin-right: 0px;

 }
#Two {
  margin-left: 20px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
#Three {
  margin-left: 20px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
#Four{
  margin-left: 20px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
a.mobile{
    display block;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    text-align: center;
    padding:7px;
    border-bottom:1px #fff;
}
a.mobile: active{
    background-color:#4a4a4a;
}
```

**JS File:**

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

/* RELEVANT CODE */

$("a.mobile").click(function(){
  $(".sidebar").slideToggle('fast');
});

$("li.dropdown").click(function(){
  $(this).find('.dropdown-content').slideToggle('fast');
});

/* END OF RELEVANT CODE */

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
```

**JSON CODE**

```
  {
    "cars": {
        "Nissan": {
            "Sentra": {"doors":4, "transmission":"automatic"},
            "Maxima": {"doors":4, "transmission":"automatic"}
        },
        "Ford": {
            "Taurus": {"doors":4, "transmission":"automatic"},
            "Escort": {"doors":4, "transmission":"automatic"}
        }
    }
}

data.cars['Nissan']['Sentra'].doors   // 4
data.cars['Nissan']['Maxima'].doors   // 4
data.cars['Nissan']['Maxima'].transmission   // automatic

for (var make in data.cars) {
    for (var model in data.cars[make]) {
        var doors = data.cars[make][model].doors;
        alert(make + ', ' + model + ', ' + doors);
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are trying to accomplish here. Normally you would use Jquery and AJAX to retrieve data from a database or send some information or request to a service that is running on the webserver.
 
It's not clear to me where the list of cars you want to retrieve is stored.

Comment: I would like to create one JSON object, that contains the multiple arrays each with several pieces of data.
In my case:

An object called DROPDOWN, containing multiple arrays each for a different make of car. In each array would be the model of car. I do not have an API at my side and I am new to JSON and AJAX. How to write the whole code with in JS. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to call on the function "myfunction" to ajax call of get?

```
function myFunction() {
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:58108/bower_components/angular-mocks/bower.json",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {
            //the data you want will be in result
              },
            error: function (err) {
                //  console.log("text loading error");
            }
        });
}
```

And you have to store your json file on your site or on other storage.
"yourpath" - the url where you will get your json file.

**Update**
you can store your json object in file with suffix of json ( like in the image below). And then call you application path with the json object.
[image]

Comment: This you have told me the syntax of AJAX. now if suppose this is my JSON object.     

 

Here I am telling the car modals with the number of doors. now what would be my nextstep. How do i store it in my JS file ? Do i need to make a separate JS file or in the same one i can store. And how? Thanks

Comment: Added the JSON object in the code above. Could you please see it and help me out. Above code is not mine but i want to make a JSON object but just with models. Could you please help.Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to get, you want to store json object in var? so why you need to call ajax?

Comment: I have made a JSON object .. And yes obvious thing that i will store it in a var and then i want to make an ajax call so that after clicking on the button all of the cars models new models can be fetched out or to be more in detail can show the detail of that particular car DYNAMICALLY. Did you get m y question now ?

Comment: I will here explain the whole scenario. I have made a web page for cars where i have different options and out of those i have one option with *DROPDOWN*. Whenever any user click on it a drop down list will be opened. there will be many options and out of those there will be one named as *View New models*. As the user clicks on it.HE/she will get to see the new models of a particular car with its detail. So for all this I need Json object which i have made made and showed here too. But now how to make an ajax call.. And how to add it in code. This is the main issue for me. Thanks

Comment: You can store the your object in file with the suffix of .json like in here- https://qiita.com/api/v1/tags.json?page=1&per_page=100

Comment: I am totally novice for json and ajax. I just have made an object and added it in an var. Now what should be my next step in the direction to fetch the information dynamically.

Comment: stored the object with the extension now how to call it from AJAX? Don't mind if you find these questions silly.

Comment: Like I wrote in my code- url: "http://localhost:58108/bower_components/angular-mocks/bower.json" change the path to your port and to your directory in the solution like in that image I attached.

Comment: I really am not gettint this :(. Can you show the code written in JSFiddle ?

Comment: What will i write in Success in ajax ??

Comment: sorry, your jsfiddle is to complicate try this link for calling ajax call http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp , there is try it your self option there. This is link is for  getting text file- http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_asyncfalse , try to do it with debug mode and see the results of the request